# Cannot connect to Postfix from Outlook or Thunderbird

Tags: postfix, outlook, login, thunderbird

I've managed to install postfix, it works, when i am logged into my VPS as root I can send and receive mail fine.  But the problem is i cannot connect with thunderbird or outlook.  I also cannot telnet to the machine remotely on port 25.  But i can telnet to it on port 25 when i am logged into the VPS.  I know port 25 is open because sending and receiving email works.  Even though it works i still opened port 25 in iptables.  I am new to this and thinking this is some kind of DNS issue, but i don't know enough to figure out where the problem is. Can anyone help?

By the way my DNS settings are as follows:

```
Type=A record host=* Value=server ip address
Type=A record host=@ Value=server ip address
Type=A record host=www Value=server ip address
Type=MX record host=@ value=mail.example.com 10
```

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to port 25?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the Postfix server is configured to listen on the public or all interfaces by editting `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

> inet_interfaces = all

Also, Thunderbird/Outlook should be using
outgoing: Secure SMTP port `465` or `587`
incoming: IMAP port `143` or `993` IMAP/TLS

Regarding the DNS; make sure it doesn't still say `mail.example.com`

Comment: thanks for replying.  I have tried those ports as well and it says connection refused.  Does that mean i need to open the port, or is that some kind of TLS, SSL issue?

Comment: is the postfix server listening on the public interface?

Comment: ok this might be where the problem is.  I tried lsof for port 465 and it didn't return anything.  Where would i need to open this up, in iptables?  Again i am new to this, so trying to solve the problem and understand whats going on at the same time.  thanks.

Comment: I added the following lines to iptables:

-A INPUT -p tcp -dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -dport 465 -j ACCEPT

But it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Outgoing traffic over port 25 is commonly blocked by *consumer* ISP's, corporate, government and college networks etc. to prevent their users from transmitting unauthorised e-mail and SPAM.

You solve that either by using the outgoing mailserver your ISP offers in your email client or by having postfix listen to a second port in addition to TCP/IP port 25 and configuring your clients such as thunderbird to use that. TCP/IP reserved port for mail submission, 587, is a common choice, as is port 465 for SMTP over SSL.

Uncomment in your master.cf:

```
#submission inet n - n - - smtpd
```

And/or

```
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

And opening those ports in your firewall.